# How to lock int that accessing via different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, int

I have this variable:

```
private static volatile int _filesInUse;
```

This variable is accessed via different threads and I want to lock this when it's value is changing in order to update my UI about the current state.

Comment: No need for *lock*,  `Interlocked.Exchange`

Comment: What does _"I want to lock this when it's value is changing in order to update my UI"_ mean exactly? What is the relation between a lock and the UI updating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For changing the integer, you have [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx). You just have to pass it in with the `ref` keyword:

```
int result = Interlocked.Increment(ref _filesInUse);
```

Use `result` along the way (it doesn't get updated when `_filesInUse` does, so it is save in your procedure to use it).

Comment: Well, it is not said in the question that OP needs an increment. OP might need simple updates then OP doesn't need `Interlocked` at all

Comment: @ixSci If it's not an increment, one of the [many other methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Interlocked_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) on `Interlocked` is probably suitable and easier to use than any other locking strategy.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, update of an `int` variable is atomic by the language rules. You don't need any lock or `Interlocked` stuff for simple updates

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a method to change that value that is synched:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public void SomeMethod() {/* code */}
```

Comment: Why all the heavy stuff? Just use `Interlocked`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `[lock][1]`

```
object lockObject = new object();

lock(lockObject)
{
// do your value changing stuff
}
```

Comment: No need for with an `int`.